# MAC OS X virtualization with KVM on the mac mini : seabios error

Tags: python, virtualization, c++, kvm-virtualization

Since I'm a legal owner of the first generation of Mac Mini with a regular Snow Leopard license,I'm trying to follow this tutorial with the goal to virtualize Mac Os X with KVM on the second part of the hard disk where I have installed Linux Ubuntu. You can find the guide here :

http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~somlo/OSXKVM/

The problem arises when I have to install/configure the seabios package. This is what happens :

....

Compiling whole program out/ccode16.o

Compiling to assembler out/asm-offsets.s

Generating offset file out/asm-offsets.h

Compiling (16bit) out/romlayout.o

Building ld scripts

Version: rel-1.7.3-18-g7093aa5-dirty-20130807_120248-ziomario-Macmini

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./tools/layoutrom.py", line 669, in

main()

File "./tools/layoutrom.py", line 633, in main

info16 = parseObjDump(infile16, '16')

File "./tools/layoutrom.py", line 564, in parseObjDump

relocsection = sectionmap[sectionname]

KeyError: '.text.asm./media/ziomario/09274c80-4a49-4f4f-9e2e-83c4a5578a04/OSXGUEST/seabios

/src/smp.c.75'

make: * [out/romlayout16.lds] Errore 1

Can someone help me to fix this error ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug building SeaBIOS with non-English messages.  Use
"LC_ALL=C make".